# combinations [fundemental counting principal]

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, gre-exam

> How many 3-digit integers can be chosen such that none of the digits
>   appear more than twice and none of the digits equal zero?

I have approached the following problem like this.

1. We know that zero is not included so  we can choose anything from 1-9 which gives us 9 options.
2. We have to select a 3 digit integer therefore we have _ _  _ 3 different stages and we can use the fundamental counting principle.
3. We have 1 constraint that is that none of the digits can be repeated more then 2 times.

So i did 9 * 9 * 9 and got 729. This is wrong though because i have not taken into account the constrain of not having 3 repeated digits.

Can anyone explain how i would remove the repeated digits from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the $9^3$ possible three-digit numbers with no zeros, subtract the number of ways that digits can be repeated three times. There are 9 numbers, each of which can be repeated three times in only one way, thus forming exactly 9 possible unique three-digit numbers that have three repeating digits:

You should obtain: $$9^3 - 9 = 720 \;\;\text{combinations}$$

Comment: Also is there another way of directly take the repeated digits in to consideration. or is this is the only way of determining.... which is to first finding out the total possibilities and then subtracting the possible repeated digits.

Comment: It could be done, but it would get awfully tedious, in comparison (counting the number of combinations with no repeating digit, counting the number of combinations with one repeating digits, and those with two repeating digits, then adding the three counts), and would be no more direct than subtracting the meager 9 invalid combinations! ;-)